# The value "123\456" in DB is read and displayed as "123￥456" in a xaml textblock

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-3.0

We have a wpf application (a Japanese project), where in a module we take a value (eg.ID = 123\456) from the DB, assign it to the text of the Textblock in xaml. 
While displaying it is displayed as 123￥456.Can anyone help me with the rootcause for this issue.

Note:
The textblock is readonly.
Not focussed.

Thanks 
Teena

Comment: I have to do quite a bit of work on a Japanese virtual machine and that little symbol causes me no end of frustration every time the keyboard switches back to a japanese keyboard.. I share your pain

Answer (score 3):

It's because of the code page used by Japanese versions of Windows.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%A5):

> In the Japanese-language locales of Microsoft operating systems, the
>   yen sign in code page 932 character encoding has the same byte value
>   as the backslash in ASCII. It is also used wherever a backslash is
>   used, such as the directory separator character and the general escape
>   character, essentially making it a backslash with the appearance of a
>   yen sign, a peculiarity that stems from JIS X 0201.

Comment: In other words - use unicode (e.g. `nvarchar`/`nchar`/`ntext` in MSSQL instead of `varchar`/`char`/`text`).